# antlr4 mismatched input 'a' expecting NAME

Tags: java, antlr4

I have simplified the code where errors happened:

```
grammar simperr;
var
  : VAR_IDS NAME EQU NAME SPLIT
  ;
VAR_IDS : ('var'|'let')+;
LETTER : [a-zA-Z$_];
NUM : [0-9];
NAME : LETTER (LETTER|NUM)*;
EQU : '=';
SPLIT : ';';
WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

and I get this:

```
var a=ijf;
enter   var, LT(1)=var
consume [@0,0:2='var',<1>,1:0] rule var
line 1:4 mismatched input 'a' expecting NAME
exit    var, LT(1)=<EOF>
```

I've tried so many ways but none of them would work.Can somebody help me?

Comment: You said "NAME definition and usage is like this:", but then never actually posted a definition of `NAME`. Please post a minimal-but-compilable grammar that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok I have simplefied the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print the token stream for your input (by adding `-tokens` as an argument to `grun`), you'll see that the `a` is recognized as a `LETTER`, not a `WORD`. This happens because both `LETTER`  and `WORD` produce a match of the same length (i.e. both match `a`) and `LETTER` comes first in the grammar (this is known as the maximum munch rule).

So you can fix your issue by moving the `LETTER` rule after the word rule, but since you never actually want to produce a `LETTER` token in any situation, the better solution would be to tell ANTLR this by marking the rule as a `fragment`.